# DHT 11 temp. And hum. Sensor always 0 values

Tags: arduino-uno, temperature-sensor

[image: DHT11]

I am trying to get my DHT 11 from the official arduino store to work (https://store.arduino.cc/grove-temperature-humidity-sensor).

I am following this guide right here:
http://wiki.seeedstudio.com/Grove-TemperatureAndHumidity_Sensor/

But I'm only getting invalid output of 0 humidity and 0 degrees.

I hope the image helps in identifying my problem.

On a side note, my sensor looks like a part is missing which is very strange and makes me doubt the right product was sent to me.

Some more information:
- Black to GND
- Red to 5v
- White is wmpty
- Yellow to d2
- Using an arduino Uno
- Output does not change whether the sensor is actually connect or not. 
- Total noob at this.

Help would be appreciated a lot!

[image: sensor detail]

Comment: that's not a DHT-11 in the photo. Why would they break out a non-connected pin like that? Also, you link to a DHT22 (white plastic), not an 11 (blue plastic)...

Comment: Well yeah the top cover is missing.. Does it carry an electrical connection though? Can you upload a detailed picture of the DHT11 module from above?

Comment: @Maximilian Gerhardt I have added an image. How do I know if it carries an electrical connection?

Comment: That is a Grove temperature and humidity sensor module with the si7005 made by seeed studio: http://wiki.seeedstudio.com/Grove-TemptureAndHumidity_Sensor-High-Accuracy_AndMini-v1.0/ They also make a module with a DHT sensor, but that is an other one.

Comment: Okay, this is not a DHT11 board. This thing has an I2C bus. Either you ordered the wrong product or they sent you the wrong product. You bought the "Grove - TH02 - I2C temperature and humidity sensor" (https://botland.com.pl/en/grove-series-for-arduino/4413-grove-th02-i2c-temperature-and-humidity-sensor.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't bought a DHT11 module but the *Grove - Temperature&Humidity Sensor (High-Accuracy & Mini) / TH02* module.

[image: module]

Thus you should use the example code [here](https://github.com/Seeed-Studio/Grove_Temper_Humidity_TH02) or follow the guide at [seedstudio wiki](http://wiki.seeedstudio.com/Grove-TemptureAndHumidity_Sensor-High-Accuracy_AndMini-v1.0/).

Datasheet of the sensor: https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/data-sheets/Si7005.pdf

Comment: That's upsetting. It's not what I ordered. I'll try to follow the guide you suggested and will let you know how that turns out. :)

Comment: @JonasBergner The sensor on this board has a superior accuracy (+- 0.5°C) when compared to the DHT11 (+- 1 °C) so I wouldn't exactly complain^^

Comment: ok this actually seems to be the product I have here with me. But i have trouble getting it to work following the instructions. I do understand that I need to connect Red to 5V and black to ground, but what does it mean to connect white to "SDA" and "SCL" to yellow? I'm kinda lost :D. I know youve already helped me a lot. I really appreciate it! @Maximilian Gerhardt

Comment: @JonasBergner SDA (Serial-DAta) and SCL (Serial CLock) are the 2 signals of the I2C bus. The Arduino Uno has its I2C pins on A4 (SDA), A5 (SCL), this is where the cables need to go. (https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Wire)

Comment: heck yeah i got it to work! without burning my house down! Thank you so much!

Comment: How does the Grove TH02 compare to the DHT22?

Comment: @DuncanC Refer to the specifications of the Si7005 (https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/data-sheets/Si7005.pdf) and the DHT11 sensor (https://www.mouser.com/ds/2/758/DHT11-Technical-Data-Sheet-Translated-Version-1143054.pdf), especially the parameters accuracy, resolution and range.

Comment: I asked how it compared to the DHT22, which is also more accurate than the DHT11. I haven't had enough coffee yet this morning to pour over data-sheets. If you know the differences off the top of your head, cool. If not I'll wait until I am more awake and slog through some data-sheets.

Comment: It looks like the DHT22 is more accurate.The DHT22 data sheet says ±2% RH, and ±0.2°C temp, where the Grove TH02 says ±4.5%RH and ±0.5°C typical (±1.0°C max).

Comment: @DuncanC oh okay I just read DHT11 instead of DHT22; yes in that case DHT22 beats this board.

Comment: The OP was trying to buy a DHT11. I started out using DHT11s and then moved to DHT22's, So I was curious as to how they compared.